# Correctly using wp_head()

Tags: theme-development

I'm working on my first theme, and I found out that I had to call `wp_header()` before `</head>`.

My header.php file has this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php the_title(); ?></title>
        <meta content='text/html;charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'>
        <meta content='utf-8' http-equiv='encoding'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/side-nav.css'>
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>
```

However, since I started calling this method my header now has some extra fluff that's messing up my layout.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Faux Pas Improv Comedy | Hello world!</title>
        <meta content='text/html;charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'>
        <meta content='utf-8' http-equiv='encoding'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://localhost/htdocs/wp-content/themes/super-plain/style.css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://localhost/htdocs/wp-content/themes/super-plain/side-nav.css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='open-sans-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A300italic%2C400italic%2C600italic%2C300%2C400%2C600&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext&#038;ver=3.8.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='http://localhost/htdocs/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=3.8.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='http://localhost/htdocs/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=3.8.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://localhost/htdocs/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
        <link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://localhost/htdocs/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
        <meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.8.1" />
        <style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
        html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
        * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
    }
</style>
    </head>
```

My question is, how do I remove the extra stuff from being added by wp_header that I don't need; and what can I absolutely not remove from wp_header?

Comment: You mean `wp_head()`?

Comment: I'd guess you could remove some of those extra stylesheets. How did they get there? Plugins? Are you adding them from your functions.php?

Comment: @JMau Yes, my bad. I've fixed the question title.

Comment: @helgatheviking I'm honestly not sure. This is a clean install of the most recent wordpress and there are not any plugins, unless there are any that come by default. My functions.php is also completely empty.

Comment: What is "extra" and what have you added yourself? Are you building a child theme?

Comment: It's just a theme that I'm building from scratch. It's my first theme. @Otto says that this stuff is for the admin bar. Is there a way to remove this, or must it be present?

Comment: Looking again, Otto is correct, that's the admin bar styling. I wouldn't worry about it. Non-logged in users won't see it. You can disable the admin bar from your profile settings, but I find it to be pretty helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That "extra stuff" is for the Admin Bar. If it's messing up your layout, then you should correct the layout so that it doesn't mess it up.

Comment: I see what is happening now. This is the first theme/time dabbling with wordpress, and I didn't anticipate this. My layout is supposed to hug the top of the page, and the admin bar is pushing my theme down which messes with a couple of the measurements. This is easily fixed, however, I don't need this in my page. Is there a way to remove these references?

Comment: There we go. I fixed the margins, but I would actually like to remove the references to the admin-bar. Is this possible?

Comment: You can turn off the admin bar in your user settings, but if your markup is done right the admin should not effect anything.

Comment: You should really make your theme not dependent on where the top of the page is. The admin bar will only appear to logged in users, not to normal readers, and so the theme should handle both cases gracefully. Adding that margin-top to the html or body normally has the effect of simply pushing down the whole page by a few pixels to fit the bar in there.

Comment: I did. I changed the troubled element from fixed to relative, so it looks fine regardless. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Get the answer here http://davidwalsh.name/remove-wordpress-admin-bar-css. Just add this function to your functions.php

```
add_action('get_header', 'remove_admin_login_header');
function remove_admin_login_header() {
    remove_action('wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb');
}
```